# Messed Up Drupal Site, truncated all cache, menu_router, registry_file and now I can't access site

Tags: routes, caching, debugging

After disabling comment module, I could not access some modules, so I researched how to get that fixed and end up following [this](https://drupal.org/node/1269452#comment-5513494). I cleared all the cache_table, menu_router and registry_file.

This is the exact command I ran:

```
TRUNCATE `cache`;
TRUNCATE `cache_block`;
TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE `cache_entity_og_membership`;
TRUNCATE `cache_entity_og_membership_type`;
TRUNCATE `cache_field`;
TRUNCATE `cache_filter`;
TRUNCATE `cache_form`;
TRUNCATE `cache_image`;
TRUNCATE `cache_libraries`;
TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE `cache_metatag`;
TRUNCATE `cache_page`;
TRUNCATE `cache_path`;
TRUNCATE `cache_token`;
TRUNCATE `cache_update`;
TRUNCATE `cache_variable`;
TRUNCATE `cache_views`;
TRUNCATE `cache_views_data`;
TRUNCATE `menu_router`;
TRUNCATE `registry_file`;
```

Now I have an empty site, I can't browse or go to anywhere. Even the front page Gives page not found error saying "/" not found.

I tried to rebuild the menu and registry with these commands but it didn't work.

```
chdir('path/to/site/root');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

registry_rebuild();
menu_rebuild();
```

I tried with drush using `drush cc all` but it says

> No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.
>   but `drush status` shows it find the site

```
 Drupal version         :  7.23
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /path/to/site/root
```

What can I do? How to get the site back after this?

Comment: Restore from the backup you took before you decided to modify the database.

Comment: @enzipher, I want to fix this.

Comment: Can you run /update.php ?

Comment: @enzipher, Yeah tried that also. Nothing happened.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is not a free support service, but questions and answers community. Can you somehow rewrite it into actual question, not a support request?

Comment: @Mołot, I think I know how the SE community works. SE demands to show what you have tried and what didn't work. That is what I have done. I ran into a problem and thus am asking a question about it.

Comment: Use -r & -l with the drush command to point it to the correct site (see http://drush.ws/) That's how I get rid of the "No Drupal site found" error.

Answer (score 3):

Best thing is to restore it from a backup to make it work.

If you want to fix it, replicate the site from a back up (db and files).
Then truncate tables one by one to see which one is causing the problem (It should be menu_router).

Truncate first all cache table and check
Truncate menu_router and check
Truncate registry_file and check.

About the code you did, try to remove registry_rebuild from your code.
Create a file fix.php and paste this code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

menu_rebuild();
```

save it into your drupal root and visit mysite.com/fix.php .

Comment: I already tried this, the admin menu is missing and lots of other modules giving blank screen.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate the site from a working backup and see which is the faulty table?

Comment: Yes it is menu_router Restoring that from the db gives me a working site but without admin menu and many modules like views not behaving properly.

Comment: Have you tried to use registry_rebuild after you rebuild menu_router?

Comment: Nope. I tried to rebuild menu though.

Comment: So, if you rebuild menu_router the site works but not properly. What happens if you rebuild_registry after?

Comment: Same thing. Nothing happens.

Comment: No, I overrode the menu_router table with the previous backup. That gives me a workable site but not properly. rebuild menu functions does nothing and registry_rebuild() also gives nothing.

Comment: can you run update.php?

Comment: Yeah, but it does not proceed since it finds nothing to update.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got no backup from *before* you messed up the site, so that the *obvious* solution - using your favourite SQL management tool (e.g. *phpMyAdmin* or the CLI SQL program) to restore from backup - is not an option?

- Create a backup *now* (using whatever database management tool you have).
- Create a clean install of the Drupal core.
- Look at your new nice and shiny database, print out the schema (a list of the tables it now contains).
- Roll back from the backup all the tables that exists in this schema, *except* the  following (all of these may not even exist in your backup):

  - `{accesslog}` – access log generated by statistics module (disabled by default);
  - `{batch}` – connects a user to his/her batch (a crashed site has no active users);
  - `{cache*}` – the cache just optimises page loads, always safe to truncate;
  - `{flood}` – flood log generated by built-in flood control;
  - `{registry_file}` - code registry, rebuilt when cache is cleared;
  - `{search*}` – loses search indices and statistics, indices is regenerated by cron;
  - `{sessions}` – loses user session  (a crashed site has no active users);
  - `{syslog}` – system events log generated by syslog module (disabled by default);
  - `{watchdog}` – loses log messages.
- Note that list above is *always* safe to exclude from rollbacks.  They only contain ephemeral data, and may contain bad data if a site has crashed.  There is a comment after each, explaining what it is used for.
- Also roll back all tables starting with `field`.
- Install all the contributed and custom modules you absolutely need, but skip those you suspect make trouble.
- Roll back from the backup all the tables that belongs to these modules, module by module.  You can see what table a belongs to because the table name always starts with the module's machine name.  Check that your site is healthy after each round of rollbacks.

Usually, this gives you back a working site, with no contents lost.